# Which Java collection type should I use?

Tags: java, collections

I'm trying to create a "Limited List" in Java. It should remove old entries if I add new entries.

e.g. If the list size is 3, and I add the 4rd item, it should remove the 1st item. Currently I solved this using `remove(0)` in a `ArrayList`, but I heard `ArrayList`s are very slow.

Is there a faster way to solve this? My current code is:

```
public class LimitedList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    private int maximum;

    public LimitedList(int maximum) {
        this.maximum = maximum;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        boolean r = super.add(t);
        while (size() > maximum) {
            remove(0);
        }
        return r;
    }

}
```

Comment: A `LinkedList` or `Queue`.

Comment: ArrayLists aren't slow at all. But it's true that it's not the best list implementation if the most common operation is to remove the first element, because it's O(N). That said, for a list of 3 elements, that really doesn't matter. You should NOT extend ArrayList or any other list though, because what you define is NOT a list. It's another data structure that can be implementing by **using** a list. For example, calling addAll() on your class would break its invariants. Using an iterator to add elements would also break its invariants. etc.

Comment: Are you sure you want it to be a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)? E.g. what should happen when calling [`add(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E))? How is [`get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) useful, if indexes *sometimes* change when adding a new value? What is the full API you need for your "Limited List"? Figure that out first, then decide whether to use/implement existing Java collections interfaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but I heard ArrayList's are very slow.

*Some operations* are slow for `ArrayList`s others for other collections. This is because an `ArrayList` uses an array behind the curtains, and for a remove operation in the head, it has to shift all the elements one to the left. Therefore in terms of big oh, removing from the head is *O(n)* for `ArrayList`s where it is *O(1)* for `LinkedList`s.

If you only want to add items in the tail of the collection and remove elements in the head, I propose you use a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

```
public class LimitedList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {

    private int maximum;

    public LimitedList(int maximum) {
        this.maximum = maximum;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        boolean r = super.add(t);
        int n = this.size();
        while (n > maximum) {
            this.removeFirst();
            n--;
        }
        return r;
    }

}
```

An important note from [@JBNizet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896847/which-java-collection-type-should-i-use/37896925#comment63247234_37896925) is that you should inherit from `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` directly, but implement a `Collection<T>`, something like:

```
public class LimitedList<T> implements Collection<T> {

    private final LinkedList<T> list;
    private int maximum;

    public LimitedList(int maximum) {
        this.list = new LinkedList<T>();
        this.maximum = maximum;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        boolean r = this.list.add(t);
        int n = this.list.size();
        while (n > maximum) {
            this.list.removeFirst();
            n--;
        }
        return r;
    }

    //implement other Collection methods...

}
```

Comment: He shouldn't extend LinkedList in the first place. A LimitedList is not a List.

Comment: @JBNizet: you are correct, he should use a `LinkedList` internally and extend from `Collection`.

Comment: @JBNizet: I've updated the answer with what I think is a better way to tackle the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet "LimitedList is not a List", can you explain that?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth: what JBNizet probably means is that `List` has a lot of contracts, for instance that adding will increment the size by one. By constructing a `LimitedList` that does not satisfies these contracts, you  are implementing a datastructure that can result in problematic behavior, since other methods rely on these contracts.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth it's not a `List` according to the Java Specification, since it has a behaviour that is mentionned nowhere in the spec nor in the doc

Comment: A LimitedList can't be a List because that would violate the Liskov substitution principle. You see, good OO design is more than putting "extends" in your class definitions. It is about getting all these rules right!

Comment: @Dici Having behavior that is mentioned nowhere does not in itself make it "not a List". *Violating* the contract of a `List` does.

Comment: [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) might be a better choice than [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html): *[`ArrayDeque`] is likely to be [...] faster than `LinkedList` when used as a queue.*

Comment: @Andreas playing on words :p that's what it meant

Comment: @Andreas How should I use a Queue for that? I tought about using a Stack, but idk how.

Comment: @JBNizet But it is much more work to add every collection method for the same result

Comment: @Florian: it is more work, but most of the methods are simply redirection to the internal collection. From a design perspective, it is the only correct way to construct a new collection.

Answer (score 2):

Please: don't give a nickel on "what you hear". Programming is about hard facts, not hearsay. You can be very sure that all the collection implementations were written by experts in the field; so the first thing would be to check the various documentation out there to assess if the operations that you need really come with a **significant performance tag** to you.
Yes, collection operations have different cost, but all of that is documented.

Then: if you are really only talking about 3, 4 elements ... do you really really think that performance matters? That would only be the case if you would be using this lists for (hundreds of) thousands of times per minute or so. Keep in mind what a modern CPU can do in a few micro seconds nowadays; and how many method calls you need to have in order for "call B is 5 nanoseconds slower" to be noticeable.

In other words: strive for good, clean (SOLID based) designs; instead of worrying about *potential* performance problems. That will pay off 10 times more compared to spending hours on topics like this.

You see: one should be really careful about "performance issues". Because:  you only realize that you have one ... when there are complains from your users. And if that happens, you don't start blindly by trying to improve this or that; no then you first do **profiling** to measure where your problems are coming from. And **then** you fix those things that need improvement.

EDIT: so your last comment indicates that you did some sort of measurement  (hint: if you would have said so directly, instead of writing "I heard that lists are slow" ... probably you would have gotten a different answers already). OK, lets assume that you did good profiling (where: even when one collection types performs slower for you, the question is still: will it be called so often to cause trouble). Anyway: what you really ant to is to understand **access patterns** that you do on your code. Do you need random access, do you iterate in lists, etc. You see, typically, a container that forgets elements ... that sounds more like a cache than a list. In that sense: do you rely on quick in-sequence retrieval of objects; or how is data accessed? Those are the questions that you have to ask yourself; and only then you can decide if you should implement your own special limited list; or if there are existing components (maybe from apache commons or guava) that give you what you need.

Comment: About the performance, I agree one should not do premature optimization but it's **always** good to use the right data-structure. He did not say his list was of size 3, he picked 3 as an example. He's implementing a data-structure, so he's right to be cautious about which DS he wraps for implementing his own. Personnally when I do a code review I'm attentive to these things because it does not cost anything to pick a reasonable DS, you just need to know the cost of the operations

Comment: Agreed. Makes sense.

Comment: @Jägermeister But sometimes I've tested collection speed and it was really slow. It took 27ms to insert something into a HashMap and iterate HashMap#values

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Queues, because this kind of collection use a FIFO procedure (First In - First Out). So the first element you inserted will be the first that goes out and you can manage simply your queue by using methods like Enqueue and Dequeue (both runs in O(1)).

Comment: Well not really because he adds to the end and removes from the head. You need a pointer to both ends, hence the use of a `LinkedList`

Comment: If you use Queues you have a pointer to the head and to the tail. 
With Enqueue(x) you add to the tail, with Dequeue() you remove the head.

Comment: So if we are talking about queues, please stick to the Java queues: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html. What I did not know is that the `Queue` interface does not enforce FIFO behaviour. Apart from that your answer is mostly right but it would be preferrable that you use the actual names of the methods and point to an implementation of `Queue` that is actually FIFO

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that I was talking about Queues as data structures implemented from scratch, in that case a FIFO implementation would be easy to manage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with writing code, best option would be not to extend any existing collection and make your own collection. For list, you can implement list interface.( recommended approach is to take AbstractList abstract class)

This will give you more control and you can design for speed.

Fastest option would be to dump the collection and simply use a array (wrap operation in a class). However, that may not be suitable for you as it will not be under collection hierarchy.